# Itext pdf 7 fails to generate a table if the column has more than 20 characters

Tags: android, itext

I have been getting this error

> "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'boolean com.itextpdf.layout.properties.UnitValue.isPointValue()' on a
> null object reference

I used try and error method and i was able to isolate the line causing the error.
I observed that the table generation was only failing for one column which is the description field and the error happened if the number of characters exceeded 30.
Here is the code

```
private  void addTitlePage(Document document,ArrayList<statement>statementArrayList,tenancy t){
           if(statementArrayList.size()>0) {
               try {
                   //add four paragraphs to enable different formatting
                   utility_functions = new Utility_functions(context);
                   Paragraph par1 = new Paragraph();
                   Paragraph par2 = new Paragraph();
                   Paragraph par3 = new Paragraph();
                   // Lets write a big header and add a new line
                   par1.add("TENANT STATEMENT" + "\r\n").setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).setBold().setFontSize(20);
                   //add invoice number and date
                   par2.add("Tenant Name: " + t.getTenant() + "\r\n").setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
                   par2.add("Apartment :" + t.getApartment() + "\r\n").setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
                   par2.setBold();
                   //ADD  a table ...invoice period, narration, amount as columns
                   Table table = new Table(new float[]{25,12,12,12,12,12,12});
                   //table.setWidth(523);
                   table.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));
                   table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Description")));
                   table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Type")));
                   table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Date")));
                   table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Number #")));
                   table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Amount")));
                   table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Currency")));
                   table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Balance")));
                   for (statement ss : statementArrayList) {
                       table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(ss.getDescription())));
                       table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(ss.getType())));
                       table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(ss.getDate())));
                       table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(ss.getNumber())));
                       table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(df.format(ss.getAmount()))));
                       table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(ss.getCurrency())));
                       table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(df.format(ss.getBalance()))));


                       Log.d("statement", ss.toString());


                   }

                   //par2.add("\r\n");
                   par3.add(table);
                   document.add(par1);
                   document.add(par2);
                   document.add(par3);

               } catch (Exception exception) {

                   exception.printStackTrace();

               }

           }

         }
```

If the first column in the table named "Description" has many characters i.e longer than 20, i get the error and the pdf is generated without the table.
If i truncate the number of characters to less than 20, the pdf document is successfully generated.

Is there a limitation on the length of the column in itext 7?
How can i overcome the above limitation because truncating the description column makes less meaning full to the user.